# API POST calls - Sending data in bulk vs sending data serially

Tags: api, rest, post, http-post, restful-architecture

I want to know the difference between sending data in bulk vs making multiple POST request to send the data. For eg:-

I've an endpoint `/data`. I want to know the difference between sending data as one API call, ie posting data in a list

```
[
    {'key1':value1,'key2':value2,'key3':value3},
    {'key1':value11,'key2':value21,'key3':value31},
    {'key1':value12,'key2':value22,'key3':value32},
    {'key1':value13,'key2':value23,'key3':value33},
]
```

vs making multiple calls on the endpoint `/data`, in this case 4 calls sending data one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I see two main differences:

- **Performance** since one call is faster than several ones because of network latency.
- **Atomicity / transactions**. You can define a set of data to be consistent with bluk requests. Everything is added or nothing. It's difficult to implement this with several calls since using transactions against a set of HTTP requests is tricky. Using only request can make easier the implementation of such issue. You can notice that it's not necessary the behavior you expect.

Moreover, if you want to support both approaches (adding a single element and several ones) with a POST method, you need to make some work to detect in which case you are. You can rely on the received content (array or not) or leverage an custom action header.

I wrote a blog post about bulk updates within RESTfuk services: https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/05/14/implementing-bulk-updates-within-restful-services/. Perhaps it could interest you...

Hope it helps you,
Thierry